# Debug.DrawRay doesn't show on editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, raycasting

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class collsionCheck : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {

    }

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 mouse = Input.mousePosition;
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(mouse, Vector3.zero);
            Debug.DrawRay(mouse, Vector3.zero, Color.green);
            if (hit)
            {
                Debug.Log("hello");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why isn't it working?, It doesn't show me an error. Gizmos is enabled but I still can't see it. I'm new to Unity so it can be something stupid.

Comment: What direction is `Vector2.zero` supposed to point in? ;) And are you.sire you want the `mouse` in **pixel space** as origin? You probably would rather use `Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition)`

Answer (score 10):

`Debug.DrawRay()` method only show if you have set the `Gizmos` option toggled on.

To see it in scene view make sure you have toggle `Gizmos` on.
[image: Scene view]

To see it in Game view you have to do the same.
[image: Game view]

However, here you are using

`Debug.DrawRay(mouse, Vector3.zero, Color.green);`

Here the ray you defined is not valid. I am assuming you want to cast a ray from your camera to some point into your game's world position so you could do something like following in `Update()`

```
Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
float distance = 100f;
Debug.DrawRay(ray.origin, ray.direction * distance, Color.green);
```

Also it is good idea to cache `Camera.main` into a variable.